# How to order nodes in a tree based on their string data?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

Below is my current code for adding a new node (on the same level). This is the section of code that needs to be modified to add an ordering property when adding newNode. In layman's terms, when the String data ahead of newNode is greater than the String data of newNode itself I need to add newNode in that spot.

```
public void traverseRight(Node v, Node newNode) {
    if(v.getData().equals(newNode.getData())){
        System.out.println(v.getData() + " was already found in the tree under " + v.getParent().getData() + ".");
    }
    else if (hasRight(v)) {
        traverseRight(v.getRight(), newNode);
    }
    else {
        v.setRight(newNode);
        newNode.setParent(v.getParent());
    }
}
```

If there's anything else that would be helpful, like more code, I have plenty of that to go around.

**Update:** Okay, so after an hour of pacing and one YouTube search of "java compareTo()," this is what I have come up with. I tried to add a few concise comments in an effort to increase the readability.

Any opinions on this method? Am I overlooking anything or doing something incorrectly/inefficiently?

```
public void traverseRight(Node v, Node newNode) {
    if(v.getData().equals(newNode.getData())){
        System.out.println(v.getData() + " was already found in the tree under " + v.getParent().getData() + ".");
    }
    else if(v.getData().compareToIgnoreCase(newNode.getData()) > 0){
        if(v.getParent().getLeft() == v){
            // MEANS V IS THE FIRST CHILD IN THIS STRUCTURE
            newNode.setParent(v.getParent());
            v.getParent().setLeft(newNode);
            newNode.setRight(v);
        }
        else{
            // V IS NOT THE FIRST CHILD, GUARANTEED TO HAVE A PREVIOUS NODE
            Node prev = getPrev(v.getParent().getLeft(), v);
            newNode.setParent(v.getParent());
            prev.setRight(newNode);
            newNode.setRight(v);
        }
    }
    else if (hasRight(v)) {
        traverseRight(v.getRight(), newNode);
    }
    else {
        // MEANS WE REACHED THE END OF THE STRUCTURE W/O A HIGHER VALUE THAN NEWNODE
        v.setRight(newNode);
        newNode.setParent(v.getParent());
    }
}
```

For the record it passes all debug tests I've run thus far.. which isn't much since it's only been working for about 10 minutes, but so far so good.

Thanks again!

**UPDATE #2:** Fails when ordering Strings with multiple numbers at the end. (Ex. Flight 22)

If I was to input Flights 1, 2, 3 and 22 my program returns:

Flight 1
Flight 2
Flight 22
Flight 3

Not the end of the world, since it's just a homework project, but I wasn't sure if anyone had any quick fixes for this. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your tags. Node.js has nothing to do with this. It's a whole different thing.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for using suggested tags!

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow. It be useful to post some properly indented code, instead of inling it with your text. Be sure to post enough code to give us a reasonable understanding of your problem. That'll help get people to answer your question better and more quickly.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the warm welcome and, I took your wise advice by adding some (actually legible) code.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have your nodes implement `Comparable`. In the `compareTo` method you can decide which fields are used for the comparison (greater, less than, or equals).

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
        return node.getName().compareTo(otherNode.getName());
    }
```

Then simply add your Nodes to a SortedSet of `<Node>` or a TreeMap. These classes will do the sorting for you by calling the `compareTo()` methods on your nodes.

You'll want to make sure that you have `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods which compare nodes for equality. This is a general requirement for using collections.

If you need to check for the existence of the node already, do this as a separate task, before adding values to the Sets to Maps.

```
if (set.contains(node)) {
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you kindly for your quick response SlipperySeal. Unfortunately, I did a little reconstruction on the method myself before I saw your answer here. If it turns out that the modified method (that I'm about to post below) is incorrect, or inefficient, I'll definitely look into implementing this logic. Thanks again!

Comment: just remember there are many advantages to using the built in collections classes. as you do more things with the nodes, manipulating them is much easier. also, don't worry about efficiency. its always better to have clean, simple understandable code. in fact, the sorting algorithms in the java collections classes are probably better than anything you or I could probably write :)

Comment: Yeah, I quickly realized that when I tried creating my own compareTo() method (for no legitimate reason) before posting this, haha. I am fairly impressed by how quickly I've been able to catch on to manipulating nodes, but there's definitely still much to learn.